# Laravel $request->url() returning unowned url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've built a small web-app which listens to some webhooks from 3rd party locations and processes the data. To verify who visits my web-app, I made a simple middleware class which registeres which ip is visiting which route with which method like so:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->ip() != "::1" && $request->ip() != "127.0.0.1") {
        Visit::create([
            'ip' => $request->ip(),
            'route' => $request->url(),
            'method' => $request->method(),
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It works nicely as a tracker, but I also found some results which I cannot explain. Next to the routes which are called on my web-app, I also find calls to domains i do not even own, so how do their requests end up at my webserver? Request to these domains also ended up at my webserver:

- http://cn.bing.com:443/cn.bing.com:443
- http://dongtaiwang.com
- http://www.baidu.com:443/www.baidu.com:443
- http://www.epochtimes.com
- http://www.so.com:443/www.so.com:443
- http://www.soso.com/login
- http://www.wujieliulan.com
- http://finalbett.com/Account/Login

Does anyone have an explaination of how this could happen? Is someone messing with their dns records, or maybe short-term redirecting to my server for some reason?